# Retrieve data from complex situation of tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables accounts & accounts_csm with following structure

```
accounts

id   name 
1    Dr.Roy
2    Noble Hospital
3    Dr.Ran
```

Here in accounts table both doctor and hospital entries are stored.

```
accounts_csm
account_id_c    doctor_hospital_id_c
1                     2
3                     2
```

Now I want to retrieve  doctor_name and respected hospital_name means

Result should be

```
Doctor_name    Hospital_name 
Dr.Roy         Noble Hospital
Dr.Ran         Noble Hospital
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
SELECT acct1.name AS doc_name, 
       acct2.name AS hospital_name
FROM accounts_csm AS acsm
LEFT JOIN accounts AS acct1 
   on acsm.account_id_c = acct1.id
LEFT JOIN accounts AS acct2 
   on acsm.doctor_hospital_id_c = acct2.id
```

Comment: @PravinG Now fixed. Thanks! I forgot to give aliases to the result columns